# How to pass multi arrays to ejs file then iterate through it

Tags: node.js, ejs

I need to render multi arrays to ejs page and iterated through it.

res.render({"mypage", {array1 : value1, array2 : value2, array3 value3});

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes, when render this page , mypage.ejs not get data also I need when looping at mypage ?

Comment: This ejs file contains multi div and classes,  I need clearly structure to get iteration this items. Thanks